# How to solve $\frac{d^2 c}{dx^2}=\frac{c^n}{a^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve an autonomous second order DE, but the exponent n makes it difficult. Would I apply a different analytical solution strategy than for $n=1,2$ or the same?

Addendum: $c=c(x(t))$

Comment: Usually one needs different methods for linear equations than from non-linear equations. This divide goes here between $n=1$ and $n>1$. For $n=1$ the equation is linear and therefore easy to solve. For $n>1$ try multiplying with $\frac{dc}{dx}$, rewrite each side as a total derivative and integrate it to get a first order ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply both members by $\dfrac{dc}{dx}$.

$$\frac{dc}{dx}\frac{d^2c}{dx^2}=\frac{c^n}{a^2}\frac{dc}{dx}$$ and integrate.

$$\frac12\left(\frac{dc}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{c^{n+1}}{(n+1)a^2}+C.$$

Then next step is still separable, but indeed more difficult,

$$\frac{dc}{\sqrt{\dfrac{c^{n+1}}{(n+1)a^2}+C}}=\pm dx.$$

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Wanting to solve for c(x), I am not sure about the last step. Why would I complicate the integral by including all constant values into the root?

Comment: @fitzy_blarb: a matter of taste. But you can't escape the additive $C$.

Comment: So this is wrong?
$$\frac{dc}{c^{n+1}}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{(n+1)a^2}+2C} \cdot dx$$

Comment: @fitzy_blarb: of course.